Unity doesn't see anything colliding
I spent 10 hours making what should be a simple 2D game in Unity, but I'm facing persistent issues with collision detection. Despite following tutorials and checking the documentation, my collisions are not being detected as expected. I've tried various approaches, including using both OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerEnter2D, but nothing seems to work. I've also checked the colliders, Rigidbody2D components, and layer settings, but I'm still stuck.
Problem is when a body with collider of 70x70 is fully in literally middle of the 10 times bigger collider Unity doesn't see anything. Also there are no other colliders that can collide with the smaller.
I implemented a script that should detect collisions between a player object and several target objects (holes). I expected the OnCollisionEnter2D method to be called when the player collides with these targets, and for points to be awarded accordingly. However, the collision detection is not firing at all. I've added debug logs to track the flow of the code, but the logs indicate that the collision methods are never triggered.
I've also created a simple test scene with basic shapes to isolate the problem, but even that doesn't work. I've spent a lot of time troubleshooting this issue, and I'm at a loss for what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Chapter1Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image crosshair; // Crosshair for aiming
    public Image[] holes = new Image[10];   // Array to hold hole prefabs
    public Canvas canvas;  // Reference to the Canvas
    public int bullets = 10; // Number of bullets available
    public TextMeshProUGUI bulletsCount; // UI element to display bullet count
    public Image blue; // Reference to the blue object
    public int points = 0; // Player's score
    public TextMeshProUGUI pointsText; // UI element to display points
    public int toSend = 0; // Index to track which hole to send next

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the bullet count display
        bulletsCount.text = bullets.ToString();

        // Find all GameObjects with the tag "hole" and store them in the holes array
        GameObject[] foundHoles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("hole");
        Debug.Log("Found " + foundHoles.Length + " holes.");

        // Assign found hole objects to the holes array
        for (int i = 0; i < foundHoles.Length && i < holes.Length; i++)
        {
            holes[i] = foundHoles[i].GetComponent<Image>();
            Debug.Log("Assigned hole: " + holes[i].gameObject.name);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Update the points display
        pointsText.text = "Points: " + points.ToString();

        // Check if there are bullets left
        if (bullets > 0)
        {
            // Check for space key press to shoot
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                // Ensure we have holes left to send
                if (toSend < holes.Length) // Check if toSend is in range
                {
                    // Set the position of the current hole to the position of the crosshair
                    holes[toSend].gameObject.transform.position = crosshair.transform.position;

                    // Increment the index for the next hole and decrement the bullet count
                    toSend++;
                    bullets--;
                    bulletsCount.text = bullets.ToString(); // Update the bullet count display
                    Debug.Log("Shot fired! Bullets left: " + bullets);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("No more holes to send.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // Log the name of the colliding object
        Debug.Log("Collision detected with: " + collision.gameObject.name);

        // Check if the collision is with the last hole sent or the blue object
        if (toSend > 0 && (collision.gameObject == holes[toSend - 1].gameObject || collision.gameObject == blue.gameObject))
        {
            points += 10; // Increment points for a successful hit
            Debug.Log("Hit! Points: " + points);
        }
    }
}

Also here are my gameObject rigidBodys and BoxColliders
The blue(from script , the first object of interaction the hole(from script, the second object of interaction

What is chapter1manager on? can you show its collider/rb and what you think it should collide with

BugFinder, chapter1manager is on just empty game object , I just also shown in my question the components of 2 games object I want to collide with.

so then it cannot collide with anything can it.. its not a real object.. the collision code needs to be on the thing that collides

Can you perhaps share a screen of your Inspector for the object with this script and relevant RigidBody 2D and Collider 2D?
Just quick basic thoughts to think of in case you missed something:

For Collision, be sure "Is Trigger?" is disabled so physics collision is registered instead of triggered only.
Is your Rigidbody 2D "Body Type: Dynamic"?
Be sure your "Collision Detection: Continuous".
Be sure your "Interpolate: Interpolate".
Be sure the collider object is active when other object enters its field.


Ok , I did it. But why I need Dynamic body ?

This allows you to move the object while considering mass property. You can also use Kinematic which neglects mass property if you dont want the object to be impacted by gravity.
